# htaccess authentication not working

Tags: .htaccess

What is wrong with this .htaccess? It's HTTP auth plus some rewrite rules. But when I enter HTTP user pass, it logs in but it gives 500 internal server error.

```
AuthUserFile /home/useraccount/.htpasswds
AuthName "Please Log In" 
AuthType Basic
require user wiki

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Comment: Did you check the apache error logs?

Comment: Also, I've never seen the `B` flag before. Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: without auth statements, everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache error logs are the best place to start (usually at `/var/log/apache2` or `/var/log/httpd`). That will tell you exactly what the problem is.

I'd guess that either the `.htpasswds` file isn't where you've specified, or there's a problem with the file contents or permissions.